# How to indicate path to external R code on published Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a PowerBI (PBI) report created using local R code for doing some plots.
Usually, the code is directly pasted within PBI but I indicate the path to the R file in my computer.
This means, that in the "R script editor" from PBI I simply have a line like: `source("C:/Users/Myself/PowerBI/Script_Plot01.r")`

Now I want to publish this report to be on-line available but I don't know 'where' to put the r code file to be available to PowerBI.
I have tried to link the source with a folder in Sharepoint, so having a line like:
`source(" https:// myself. sharepoint.com /PowerBI /Script_Plot01.r  ")`

But it doesn't work. I got the following "Script Runtime Error":

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
```

I want to have external sourced R code because I re-use the same code many times for multiple plots, so it is much more efficient than copy-paste it. Also, it helps on keeping everything properly updated.

I have asked this also in the PowerBI official community, but no answer. Apparently, PBI may not support this nor have a simple solution.

Therefore I wonder if there is any way from R that I can link to a sharepoint folder (or similar) where to have the code and ask R to execute it.

Many thanks for your help!

Susana.

Comment: You can't use local code, only the supported packages in the service

Comment: Hi Jon, I use the supported packages. The issue is where the R code file is located.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that right, is this code for use in the visual or the power query part?

Comment: In the visual part. (In the query side I can link to an external/sharepoint file)